# Rust math library for large numbers?

Tags: rust, math

I see a lot of folks rolling hairy implementations for dealing with u128, u256. Integer square roots, etc. Are there any general purpose libraries that folks have seen?

Comment: I have had some success with [primitive-types](https://docs.rs/primitive-types/) and [rust_decimal](https://crates.io/crates/rust_decimal).

Answer (score 6):

The [math library](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/libraries/math) from the SPL repo is popular

Comment: thanks! it looks like it only has a handful of functions, might be enough for what i need though